# PyMySQL и создание папок в базах данных

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, table, pymysql

Появилась необходимость создать папку в базе данных. Вообще возможно ли это, и чем я могу воспользоваться?

Я представляю себе это как дерево, ибо нужно записывать много информации о пользователе:

```
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE database_1")

# database_1 именно база данных - как показано выше.
# через еще несколько несколько команд создания в базе данных:
database_1
    folder_user_1
        user_info
        info_about_something_1
        info_about_something_2
        info_about_something_3
    folder_user_2
        user_info
        info_about_something_1
        info_about_something_2
        info_about_something_3
    # И так далее...
```

Нашел вопросы по типу "Как создать базу данных в локальной папке", но увы это не подходит так как я пользуюсь базой данных на aws, да и задачи особо не решает, ведь будет вестись поиск по людям (есть в базе данных / нет в базе данных) и от этого зависит дальнейший алгоритм.

Существует ли команда по типу `CREATE FOLDER folder_name`? Что-нибудь вроде того...

Что можно использовать для этих целей? Буду очень благодарен за примеры кода создания папки, если они вообще есть и их так можно назвать. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Никаких папок в базах данных не предусмотрено. Если надо хранить какие-то данные, не подходящие по смыслу под базу данных - храни их в файловой системе, там папок можно насоздавать вагон.

Comment: Если информация о пользователях структурирована, то можно воспользоваться реляционной базой данных. Если данные не структурированы, то можно либо воспользоваться форматом структуры данных БД - EAV, либо копать в сторону не реляционных БД.